# Is WIFI safe for humans?

Tags: radiation

I have wifi on at my home almost all the time. I learned that the frequency of visible light is around several hundreds of THz, while the frequency of wifi is only several GHz, which is only 1:100,000. But I'm not sure how the amplitude of wifi wave compares to the amplitude of the visible light? Are the frequency and the amplitude the only concerns when we talk about the radiation? Can someone educate me to quantify the effect wifi radiation could have in our life?

Comment: Welcome to BiologyBeta.SE. Your question is off-topic here. It would be on-topic on [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). But before asking, notice that [this post](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/are-wifi-waves-harmful) probably already answers your question.

Comment: what is being said here is that there is not enough evidence to sustain a conclusion here, and so its not a great question for this site.  on the other hand you can also take that as the answer to your question.

Comment: so digging a little more into your question , this might also be a physics question.  there are two aspects of electro magnetic radiation which are good places to start.  first is the power of the signal, which is related to amplitude and frequency of the wave, but is on the order of Watts usually. The second is how often the frequency of the radio wave is absorbed by the body and what.  that is much more controversial.  1 GHz waves are have a wavelength of about 30 cm - or about a foot.  this is why radio waves tend to pass through walls and through bodies.  Can this still be harmful?

Comment: its not a strong number. but small amounts of power concentrated in tiny spaces can be harmful.  so that's the controversy.  Its hard for many of us to believe that a fraction of a watt deposited extremely rarely in the body can be harmful in an extraordinary way.  (say more than commercial radio transmissions)  but its very hard to say it isn't with enough confidence to shut off speculation. so that might give you an idea of what sort of answer you might get.

Comment: Thanks @shigeta, actually I asked the same question at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119806/is-wifi-safe-for-humans before I asked here, but unfortunately I met a group of politicians.

Comment: @shigeta thanks for your idea. So how do you think if we are exposed to our home lamp vs to the home wifi? Can I say the radiation from the visible light from home lamp is much stronger than it from the wifi?

Comment: yes but also visible light does not penetrate the skin (much).  there's really no way to definitively end the argument. that's why you might have gotten some static here.  although that is also true for most scientific questions too - very few scientific papers definitively come to a proof of one thing or another.  a lot of people ignore this when calling questions 'subjective'.